# Click function by Enrr

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-templates

i have click function:

```
$("#but").on('click', function(){
       $.post('/chat/send/', {
            id: $(this).attr("name"), text: $('#text').val(), chat_id: $(".message-box").attr("chat-id"),
                }, function(response) {
            var options = '';
        $.each(response.data, function() {
        options += '<p><b>' + this[0] + ':</b> ' + this[1] + '</p>';
            });
        $('#text').val('');
        $('.message-box').html(options);
        });
        });
```

When i try to add function of submiting an input by Enter key it nothing happend. This function with Enter submit:

```
$('#text').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
           $("#but").on('click', function(){
            $.post('/chat/send/', {
            id: $(this).attr("name"), text: $('#text').val(), chat_id: $(".message-box").attr("chat-id"),
                }, function(response) {
            var options = '';
        $.each(response.data, function() {
        options += '<p><b>' + this[0] + ':</b> ' + this[1] + '</p>';
            });
        $('#text').val('');
        $('.message-box').html(options);
        });
        });
        }
    });
```

In HTML i have:

```
<input id="text" type="text" name="message-text" size="63">
<input id="but" type="submit" name="Send" value="Send">
```

Comment: on keypress you are not not firing the action you want, you are attaching the event handler to the #but element

Comment: Thx mate, i am new in jQuery

Comment: @Hellbea you can check my edited answer it's more optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are attaching the `keypress` event with the `click` inside, so to solve this issue ; here is a suggestion

**1st** try to factorise repeated code , so that if there is any edit you'll have to do it just once :

```
function sendReq(data){
        $.post('/chat/send/', data, function(response) {
                var options = '';
            $.each(response.data, function() {
            options += '<p><b>' + this[0] + ':</b> ' + this[1] + '</p>';
                });
            $('#text').val('');
            $('.message-box').html(options);
            });
    }
```

so now you are having a function that send your request, now you'll handle the event where you function will be fired , it's simply by typing

```
$('#text').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            var data = {id: $(this).attr("name"), text: $('#text').val(), chat_id: $(".message-box").attr("chat-id")}
            sendReq();
        }
    });
```

and you do the same thing for the click .